# Show index page if $_GET["page"] isn't set

Tags: php

I'm making a CMS with functions to add your own pages. However, I'm stuck.

As you can see, I've posted my code below. This code creates the pages which have been put in the database.

Problem is, I want to show the index page if $_GET['page'] isn't set. Index page is ID 1. The user cannot delete ID 1 from the backend.

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM paginas');
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == $row['name']) {
            ?>
                // content content...
            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
                // show ID 1 content...
            <?php
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "The user has not created any pages yet!";
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: try `===` at `if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] === $row['name'])` also you can check `!empty($_POST["page"]` and `$_POST["page"] != ""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
if (isset($_POST["page"]) && !empty($_POST["page"])) {
    if($_GET['page'] === $row['name']){
        print_r($row); // show data specific to id if page is set
    }
}else{  
    //echo "Page is not set";
    if($row['id'] == 1){  //show data of id=1 if page is not set
        print_r($row);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is ID 1? Do you mean `index.html?id=1`?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM paginas WHERE id="1"` or `SELECT * FROM paginas WHERE name="index"`, both are correct - I want to display all the index items from the database if the ?page= isn't set - but I'm not sure how to do that